# New PARSE dashboard not loading

Tags: parse-platform, dashboard

I turned on the new beta, PARSE dashboard.  Now getting a JS load error when loading in Chrome and Safari.

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "dashboard/data/Migration/MigrationStep.react"(anonymous function) @ dashboard.bundle.js:36(anonymous function) @ dashboard.bundle.js:36t @ dashboard.bundle.js:1(anonymous function) @ dashboard.bundle.js:40t @ dashboard.bundle.js:1(anonymous function) @ dashboard.bundle.js:1t @ dashboard.bundle.js:1(anonymous function) @ dashboard.bundle.js:1(anonymous function) @ dashboard.bundle.js:1
```

Anyone know how to turn off the new JS dashboard, and just go back to a working HTML dashboard!?

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://dashboard.parse.com/apps and the hover your mouse over the Parse logo on top left corner of the page. Two options appear one of them is `Switch back` which lets you go back to old dashboard.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - but the page didn't load when this was a problem.  Looks like you've fixed the JS loading issue now.  But when the JS didn't load, the whole page didn't load.